# How to decode time stored as integer in SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, datetime, type-conversion

I got some dump of SQL Server database to extract some data out of it. In particular I have to extract start and end datetime of appointments. I managed to identify date column which stores values like 41640, 41641 and so on.
Casting those values into date time (`cast (41640) as datetime)`) gives nice date with no time (`2014-01-03 00:00:00`).

Next there are two columns which I suspect (based on their names: from, to) represent start and end time. The problem is that values in those two columns are either NULLs or integers in the range from 29 to 82. Looking for any hints how to convert those values into time of the day (these should be pretty much even times).

Here are some sample values:

```
date, from, to
41640   29  68
41640   29  68
41640   29  68
41640   29  68
41640   29  68
41641   29  68
41641   29  68
41641   29  31
41641   29  30
41641   41  41
```

Comment: You're asking *us* to guess on the encoding system used on *your* database? Ask the designer?

Comment: I seriously doubt those are start and end times of appointments.  Otherwise you have many appointments overlapping and at least one appointment that has zero duration.

Comment: @DaleK If I could ask the designer I would gladly do so but I can't. This is a reverse engineering task and yes I am asking you for help.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Yes they are overlapping and that is expected (these are appointments for for different persons/locations so they can occur at the same time)

Comment: In other words what I'm asking is if there is any well known method of storing time in SQL Server that looks like this. I know of methods where date is stored as number of seconds since midnight, or fraction of of 24 hours expressed in minutes, perhaps there is another method that would explain those numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Values 'from' and 'to' represent number of quarters passed since midnight. So for Example `28*15min = 420mins. 420min/60min = 7h (am)`. `68*15min = 1020min / 60min = 17h`.
These are actually for even hours, but knowing this it's pretty easy to calculate minutes too.